# Error in Unscale function of R

Tags: r, scale, normalization

The following is a column that I normalised using r's scale function

```
      Percentage
      18.12807882
      11.91957875
      0
      9.523809524
      6.789250354
      1.654411765
      8.027327071
      10.13061485
      7.576493443
      8.230958231
      14.82579689
      12.27436823
      26.59574468
      15.7537155
```

I have used scale to normalise the same.I have predicted the following output using a decision tree.

```
 -0.5041396  0.6601254 -0.2216793
```

How do i convert this to its normal unit. I have tried

```
  unscale(norm.data = DF$Percentage, vals = Q,col.ids = Q)
```

that yields an error: Incorrect dimension of data to unscale.

What should i be doing exactly. I need some guidance.

Comment: Where did you find function `unscale`? In what package?

Comment: Saw it used on Stack overflow

Comment: And R studio shows no error. In case there is another method please let me know.

Comment: You might try `unscale(vals = DF, norm.data = DF, col.ids = "Percentage")`. And this seems to come from package `DMwR`.